# how are dns queries charged

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, g-suite, amazon-route53

I am using the following services on aws
EC2-Under free tier
Route-53
In route 53 I made an A record Initially for my-domain.com
after that I added an alias record for www.my-domain.com and an MX record for my custom domain gmail account. Since then I am getting a sudden surge in the number of DNS queries. Can someone explain why this is? Are DNS queries made for every mail sent and/or recieved. If yes, then how many?
Also, if I use Amazon SES, will I still get these many DNS queries?

Comment: To you setup `TTL` for records witch are you made? `Amazon Route 53` does not have a default `TTL` for any record type. You must always specify a `TTL` for each record so that caching `DNS `resolvers can cache your `DNS` records to the length of time specified through the `TTL` If your `TTL` is short another DNS servers discard record from cache and ask you again for name resolution. Maybe becouse of that you have to menu queries.

Comment: Route 53 costs $0.40 per million queries. There are better places to try to optimize costs, if that's what you're trying to achieve. In practice every email received (inc spam) will likely cause an MX lookup. Without DNS caching mentioned above every resource load could be a DNS query.

Comment: So to reduce the number of DNS queries, should I increase my ttl for every record? @2707974

Comment: Some recommended value `SOA TTL  recommended >= 3600.
SOA refresh  recommended >= 14400.
SOA retry  recommended >= 3600.
SOA expire  recommended >= 604800.
SOA minimum  recommended between 300 and 86400.`

Comment: What about A record and MX records? What should their TTL be? @2707974

Comment: Try with `3600`

Comment: If I make it 1day, will that cause problems?

Comment: The TTL establishes a worst case scenario if you make a mistake.  If you set it for 1 day and the record was wrong, it will take up to 1 day for any subsequent corrected value to be globally visible.  How many DNS queries are we talking about, anyway?

Comment: I have made sure that the DNS isn't wrong. It's been tested. I am getting about 800 queries per day. The thing is, I don't mind the number of queries, I just wanted to understand why they surged after I added MX records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine why your DNS queries have increased, enable logging for Route53. Then you can review the log files to see who is requesting lookups on your domain records and for which records. You will probably find that the search engines are part of your increase.

To minimize DNS lookups, manage the TTL settings for each of your records (Resource Records). For some settings you may want a short TTL, but for other records (SOA, MX, etc.) you set longer periods such as a day (86400 seconds) or a week (604800) or even longer. I set my TTL to be long and before making changes drop the TTL. Then I wait the old TTL time before making changes if the change propagation timing is important.

Do email servers check my DNS servers for each email? This depends on the email server's setup. Typically an email server will try to verify who is sending the email to prevent SPAM. If you are sending emails to the same email server, you should not see a bunch of lookups from the same server. If you are sending emails to a wide variety of email addresses, then lookups will be greater. To minimize this, set a long TTL on your MX and SOA records. Your email client will also lookup your MX record. This includes lookups from SES.

For the most part Route53 charges $0.40 per million queries.

Here is an article that reviews some popular DNS servers including Route53. Buyer beware on product reviews, but this article will give you an indication on pricing and what to look for.

[Top 5 Best DNS Hosting Providers of 2017](https://stratusly.com/best-dns-hosting-cloudflare-dns-vs-dyn-vs-route-53-vs-dns-made-easy-vs-google-cloud-dns/)

In summary, I don't worry too much about DNS queries for domains. Provided that the TTL values are set correctly, the more queries the better. This means traffic growth. You will always have a certain amount of garbage traffic from search engines, spammers, hackers, etc. Just the cost of being on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem isnt the number of queries. I have another website that is running on aws ec2 instance, but I never get any DNS queries there. I think the difference is that there are no A-Name records on the other account's route-53 settings. I only added the elastic IP of the ec2 instance to the domain registrar's( GoDaddy) settings. Can I do that here?